# How can I calculate p(x=0 or y=0) when the variance is maximized?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

> The random variables $X$ and $Y$ have join probability mass function $p(x,y)$ for $x\in\{0, 1\}$ and $y\in\{0,1,2\}$.   Suppose that $3p(1,1) = p(1,2)$ and $p(1,1)$ maximises the variance of $XY$.   Calculate the probability that $X$ or $Y$ is zero.

Then I proceed to make the table;

[image]

$P(0,0)+P(0,1)+P(0,2)+P(1,0)+P(1,1)+ 3P(1,2) = 1$

$P(X=0)+P(Y=0)-P(X=0 , Y=0)+ 4 P(1,1)=1$

> Therefore, $P(X=0 \cup Y=0)=1-4 P(1,1)$

My question is how can I calculate the probability that X or Y is zero when I maximizes the variance of XY?

I post the graph:

[image]

***Extra question: Why is no 0(cero) the correct answer? if x=0.13 maximize the variance?***

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $z=p(1,1)$, so then $p(1,2)=3z$

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(XY) & =  p(1,1)+2p(1,2) \\ & = 7z \\[2ex]
\mathsf E\big((XY)^2\big) & = p(1,1)+4p(1,2) \\[1ex] & = 13z\\[2ex]
\mathsf{Var}(XY) & = \mathsf E\big((XY)^2\big) - \big(\mathsf E(XY)\big)^2 \\[1ex] & = 13z-49z^2\end{align}$$

So what value of $z\in[0;1]$ maximises $13z-49z^2$ ?

Comment: My question was wrong edited,  was an intersection and no a union. Nevertheless, I believe that your answer still true. X=0, will be the correct answer.

Comment: No, that's not the value that maximises the variance. @JulietaR

Comment: My bad, I didn't calculate the derivative, 13=49*2x then ( x=13/98 ), is that correct? x=0.1326

Comment: I re write my question , we know that x belongs to [0,1] discrete and I have x=.1326 , why don't choose 0 then?

Comment: That's $p(1,1)=0.1326$, @Julieta, so $P(X=0\cup Y=0) = 1-4(0.1326)=0.4696$

Comment: Thanks you so much! @Graham Kemp.